# Apache URL rewrite with multiple param replacement

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Need help in apache rewrite condition for followings :

Original URL :

> **http**://www.test.foo.com/SSO/login?service=http%3A%2F%2F**www.bar.com**%2Fc%2Fportal%2Flogin

What I need is :

> **https**://www.test.foo.com/SSO/login?service=http%3A%2F%2F**www.test.foo.com**%2Fc%2Fportal%2Flogin

Following are my configs :

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName www.test.foo.com
    ServerAdmin admin@www.test.foo.com
    ServerAlias www.test.foo.com

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/www.test.foo.com.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/www.test.foo.com.access.log combined

    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyVia On

    <Proxy *>
    AddDefaultCharset Off
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*?)www\.bar\.com(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/?(SSO/.*)$ https://www.test.foo.com/$1?%1www.test.foo.com%2 [R,NE,L]

    ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/

</VirtualHost>
```

With above configs I'm able to redirect from http to https. Now The issue is in the request header location I'm still getting

> **http**://www.test.foo.com/SSO/login?service=http%3A%2F%2F**www.bar.com**%2Fc%2Fportal%2Flogin

Can anyone help me or suggest me on rewrite conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*?)www\.bar\.com(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(SSO/.*)$ https://www.test.foo.com/$1?%1www.test.foo.com%2 [R,NE,L]
```

Comment: Thanks For the Answer. You just made my day...

However, If I see the request header from network, it still shows me old URL in location..  

""Location: <//www.test.foo.com/SSO/login?service=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bar.com%2Fc%2Fportal%2Flogin%3Fp_l_id%3D11419>""

Any Idea on this ??

Comment: However, If I see the request header from network, it still shows me old URL in location.. ""Location: <//www.test.foo.com/SSO/login?service=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bar.com%2Fc%2Fportal%2Flo‌​gin%3Fp_l_id%3D11419>"" Any Idea on this ??

Comment: This rule is to redirect that URL to new one. If some html source is still sending old URL then you will see it.